# Accepting bounties for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, bounties

I would like to know why in bounties we can not accept a comment as bounty , because sometimes in comments you can see the best solution for your question but you can't accept it and award it with reputation.

I know that comments aren't assumed as answers and upvoting them doesn't add any reputation but, it would be better if for question with bounty there are a possibility to accept comments as right answer.

Comment: IMO, being able to convert a comment to an answer would be better...

Comment: I think that Danny's answer should be converted into an answer

Comment: You can already convert your own comment to an answer by... posting it as an answer. Converting other people's comments to answer would be a terrible idea.

Comment: I agree with @DannyBeckett, It's a good idea to be able to Convert the correct comment to an answer, it would be more useful for others who search for same question too.

Comment: A comment wasn't posted as an answer without a reason. I'd be ashamed if my comments were migrated to an answer without me knowing…

Comment: @slhck Who says you don't have to know? SO has a pretty good notification system already in place.

Comment: @Gaffi Well, I'd rather have someone ask me to make my comment a proper answer, which I can then actually *write* :)

Comment: More persons may give more comments, but a answer will be specified by a single person. He is the capable for getting bounty points. That's it... cool

Answer (score 14):

Tell the person to post their comment as an answer and you will award it the bounty. This sort of thing happens all the time. If they don't post it and the bounty expires, post the answer yourself so it can get the attention it deserves. If you still feel you need to reward the user, go upvote one of their better answers.

Awarding bounties to comments is a bad idea. Comments are designed to be inferior to answers: there's no rep, no revision history, no way to edit ones older than 5 minutes (or that don't belong to you), they are easily removed, and the biggest thing: the whole system is designed around them already.

Just tell the user to post an answer.

Comment: I agree with everything except *go upvote one of their better answers*. This sort of random upvoting should be avoided, or at the very least the voter should check this is a worthy answer.

Comment: @dystroy - "*better answers*" does imply some quality check being done prior to pushing the button!

Comment: It would be great if there was a `promote to answer (which would bring you to a pre-filled answer page, ready for editing)` and under flags, a `demote to comment` which if moderated, allows the comment even if the user has not got enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, post a new [`Q & A`](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) regarding the same post. if and only if the commented user is not posting the useful information as answer. Posting it as an answer by yourself on the same post may not attract other users as your post will be at bottom of all the posts. This is purely my thought.

I believe the post is more important as it has been for a bounty.